# reading two variables from awk output

Tags: bash, awk

I have code of something like the following.

```
awk '{ print $1, $2}' file | 
while IFS= read A B
do 
echo $A
if [ "$B" -eq "16" ];
then 
  grep -A 1 $A $1 | python unreverse.py  
else
  grep -A 1 $A
fi
done
```

where the awk command outputs a string and a number for each line in file. I don't quite understand how to get the while loop to work, however. It is not splitting the line properly because B is empty and I get "integer expression expected".

Comment: change your debug line to `echo "A="$A "\tB=" $B`. Good luck.

Comment: Why use awk at all in this case?  If all you really want is the first two words of each line split by whitespace, `while read A B _; do ... done < file` should work, putting the rest of the line into `$_` which you can simply ignore.

Answer (score 2):

You are essentially undefining IFS with `IFS= read A B`, so word splitting *does not occur* and all the input is captured into $A. Simply remove `IFS=`, or use `IFS=" "`, and you should be satisfied